# how to set adduser home directory permission on busybox

Tags: busybox

I'm using busybox's adduser to create home direcory.

```
adduser foo
```

I found the directory which created in a strange permission drwxs-xr-x  (with setgid flag)

Is there any config file which can let it be drwxrwsrwx

Comment: Why not just simply change the permission afterword? Busybox is not a greatly sophisticated Linux and lacks a certain amount of configurability I have found in some cases.

Comment: I guess there is a tip to modify the default settings.